# Docker : Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/192.168.32.4] failed

Tags: spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka

I have one eureka server that I have also  `@EnableEurekaServer` on the `EurekaServerApplication` and mapped `@EnableEurekaServer`
annotation and deployed the micro services.

This is the Eureka-Server docker config

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server
  zipkin:
    base-url: http://zipkin:9411

server:
  ports:
    - "8761:8761"
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
  server:
    max-threads-for-peer-replication: 0
```

I have 4 eureka clients

Apigw client

```
server:
  port: 8083

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  zipkin:
    base-url: http://zipkin:9411
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: customer
          uri: lb://CUSTOMER
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/customers/**

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
```

Customer client

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: customer
  datasource:
    password: password
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/customer
    username: ornaccode
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
  zipkin:
    base-url: http://zipkin:9411
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: localhost:5672
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    fetchRegistry: true
    registerWithEureka: true
    enabled: false
```

Fraud client

```
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  application:
    name: fraud
  datasource:
    password: password
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/fraud
    username: ornaccode
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
  zipkin:
    base-url: http://zipkin:9411

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    enabled: false
```

Notification client

```
server:
  port: 8082
spring:
  application:
    name: notification
  datasource:
    password: password
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/notification
    username: ornaccode
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
  zipkin:
    base-url: http://zipkin:9411
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: rabbitmq:5672
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    enabled: false

rabbitmq:
  exchanges:
    internal: internal.exchange
  queues:
    notification: notification.queue
  routing-keys:
    internal-notification: internal.notification.routing-key
```

My Docker Compose file

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ornaccode
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
    networks:
      - spring
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.11-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - spring
  eureka-server:
    image: remymumoh/eureka-server:latest
    container_name: eureka-server
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
  apigw:
    image: remymumoh/apigw:latest
    container_name: apigw
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
  customer:
    image: remymumoh/customer:latest
    container_name: customer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
  fraud:
    image: remymumoh/fraud:latest
    container_name: fraud
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
  notification:
    image: remymumoh/notification:latest
    container_name: notification
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
  spring:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

Whenever I deploy my containers and try to run them Eureka client throws an error

```
2022-09-08 09:16:48.122  INFO [api-gateway,,] 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on POST request for "http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/apps/API-GATEWAY": Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/192.168.96.4] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/192.168.96.4] failed: Connection refused stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/apps/API-GATEWAY": Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/192.168.96.4] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/192.168.96.4] failed: Connection refused
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.register(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:876)
        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121)
        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:101)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/192.168.96.4] failed: Connection refused
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        ... 35 more
2022-09-08 09:16:48.122  WARN [api-gateway,,] 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: I/O error on POST request for "http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/apps/API-GATEWAY": Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/192.168.96.4] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/192.168.96.4] failed: Connection refused
2022-09-08 09:16:48.146  WARN [api-gateway,,] 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/e7883c75d77a:api-gateway:8083 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:876) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:101) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2022-09-08 09:16:48.147  WARN [api-gateway,,] 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:876) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:101) ~[eureka-client-1.10.14.jar:1.10.14]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Can anyone tell me what am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: Hi @DiegoNieto no ididn't